# How to do animated side to side motion with react-motion

Tags: reactjs, react-motion

I want to make a div go from side to side 3 times after clicking a button.  I can accomplish it using the code below. [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5wnksspr/1/)

```
var Thing = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      left: 0
    }
  },
  sideToSide: function(count = 1) {
    if (count <= 6) {
      this.setState({ left: this.state.left === 0 ? 45 : 0 })    
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.sideToSide(count + 1)
      }, 200)      
    }     
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Motion style={{ left: spring(this.state.left) }}>
          {(a) => (
            <div style={{ marginLeft: a.left }}>
              Moroni 10:3-5
            </div>
          )}
        </Motion>
        <button onClick={() => this.sideToSide()}>side to side</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

but I was wondering if there was a better/different way to do this with react-motion besides changing state and passing the changes to `<Motion/>`.  Is there an option like passing an array of styles that animate in sequence like this (or something like it)?

```
<Motion styles={[
  { marginLeft: '45px' },
  { marginLeft: '0px' },
  { marginLeft: '45px' },
  { marginLeft: '0px' },
  { marginLeft: '45px' },
  { marginLeft: '0px' }
]}>
 {...}
</Motion>
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @user2030592 nope.

Comment: Found out this use case is not meant to be solved by react-motion so I used GSAP for this